# vite-pwa-plugin not fetching manifest on production build

Tags: progressive-web-apps, vite, manifest

I deployed a website on the server with the plugin installed and configured in the vite.config.js file.

When I open the website. I noticed the manifest file doesn't seems to be loaded (resolved in 404), but the file exist in the project root folder as shown in the screen shot below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gC4K.png)

[As the official doc said](https://vite-pwa-org.netlify.app/guide/)

"If you build your application, the Web App Manifest will be generated and configured on the application entry point, the service worker will be also generated and the script/module to register it in the browser added."

As I checked, it dose generate the file and insert a link element point to "/manifest.webmanifest".

The file do loaded in development mode though, that means the config do the works right?

Are there anythings I missed in the configuration?

```js
VitePWA({  
  registerType: 'autoUpdate', 
  includeAssets: ['**/*.{png}'], 
  manifest: {  
    name: 'vite-vue-pwa',  
    short_name: 'vite-vue-pwa',  
    icons: [ 
      {  
          src: '/assets/favicon/android-chrome-96x96.png',  
          sizes: '96x96',  
          type : 'image/png'  
      }, 
      {  
          src: '/assets/favicon/android-chrome-192x192.png',  
          sizes: '192x192',  
          type : 'image/png'  
      }, 
      {  
          src: '/assets/favicon/android-chrome-512x512.png',  
          sizes: '512x512',  
          type: 'image/png', 
          purpose: 'any' 
      }, 
    ],  
    theme_color: '#000000',  
    background_color: '#000000',  
    display: 'standalone'  
  },  
  devOptions: { enabled: true },  
  workbox: {  
    cleanupOutdatedCaches: true,  
    globPatterns: ['**/*.{js,css,html,ico,jpg,json,png,txt,svg}'], 
    runtimeCaching: [  
      {  
        urlPattern: ({ url }) => url.pathname.startsWith('/api'),  
        handler: 'NetworkFirst',  
        options: {  
          cacheName: 'api-cache', 
          cacheableResponse: { statuses: [0, 200] } 
        }  
      } 
    ]
   }
 }]
```

Comment: In the end, it was cause by the server not having the MIME type setting to serve .webmanifest file.